# WebStorm: How to remove all unused methods from Angular project

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am really struck and trying to find a way to remove all unused methods in Angular project

[image]

Basically I am restructuring the whole project and changing logic to accommodate the new structure. Above is the example screenshot.

Upon hitting <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> > I did not find anything to remove all `unused methods` at a go.

Tried the code -> code cleanup. But no luck

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this (likely because such quick fix would be rather unsafe, because not all methods that are not called explicitly in your code are actually unused - like different lifecycle hooks). Anyway, if you miss it, please feel free to file a feature request to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB